# How to do this simple animation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks on a nav link I need the bottom image to come underneath it with a nice glide. Kind of like the jQuery lavalamp plugin:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

but instead of hover it should come underneath the nav item on click.

Here's my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/e88CL/

jQuery:

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('span#bottom-image').animate({
        left: '+=' + $(this).offset().left + 'px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Most Popular:</li>
        <li><a href="#">This Week</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This Month</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">All Time</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span id="bottom-image"></span>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 nav { position: relative; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 20px; }
 nav ul {}
 nav ul li { float: left; }
 nav ul li a { display: block; padding: 0 50px; }

 span#bottom-image { width: 100px; height: 10px; background: red; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

As you can see in the fiddle, it doesn't quite do what it should. How to achieve this?

Comment: You're always adding pixels to the left, so it's always increasing in the offset number. Try comparing if the clicked offset is greater than or less than the actual one (save it before on a var), then sum or subtract as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. You have to adjust the width.
2. You have to just set the `left`, not increase it.

Try something similar to this:

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('span#bottom-image').animate({
        left: $(this).offset().left,
        width: $(this).outerWidth()
    }, 300);
});
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e88CL/1/

---

I've done something similar a while back:
Check it out here: [natrazyle.com](http://www.natrazyle.com/) (hover over the menu),
and here: [happyheartwsine.com](http://www.happyheartswine.com/) (hover over the rectangles under the slideshow).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('span#bottom-image').animate({
        left: $(this).offset().left + $(this).width()/2 + 'px'
    }, 1000);
});​
```

And here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e88CL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ctl = $(e.target).position().left,
        t = $('span#bottom-image'),
        tl = t.offset().left,
        w = t.width()/2,
        a = ctl - tl + w,
        s = a < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    t.stop().animate({
        left: s + '=' + Math.abs(a) + 'px'
    }, 300);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e88CL/4/)